# How to use Reactor to dispatch events to multiple consumers and to filter events based on event data?

Tags: events, reactor, project-reactor

I'm evaluating Reactor (https://github.com/reactor/reactor) if it would be suitable for creating an event dispatching framework inside my Spring / enterprise application.

First, consider a scenario in which you have an interface `A` and concrete event classes `B`, `C`, and so on. I want to dispatch concrete events to multiple consumers i.e. observers. Those are registered to a global `Reactor` instance during bean post processing. However, you can register them dynamically. In most cases there is one producer sending events to multiple consumers at high rate.

I have used `Selector`s, namely, the `ClassSelector` to dispatch the correct event types to the correct consumers. This seems to work nicely.

```
Reactor reactor = ...
B event = ...
Consumer<Event<B>> consumer = ...

// Registration is used to cancel the subscription later
Registration<?> registration = reactor.on(T(event.getClass()), consumer);
```

To notify, use the type of the event as a key

```
B event = ...
reactor.notify(event.getClass(), Event.wrap(event));
```

However, I'm wondering if this is the suggested way to dispatch events efficiently?

Secondly, I was wondering that is it possible to filter events based on the event data? If I understand correctly, `Selector`s are only for inspecting the key. I'm not referring to event headers here but to the domain specific object properties. I was wondering of using `Streams` and `Stream.filter(Predicate<T> p)` for this but is it also possible to filter using `Reactor` and `Selector`s? Of course I could write a delegating consumer that inspects the data and delegates it to registered consumers if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper object called [`Selectors`](http://reactor.github.io/docs/api/reactor/event/selector/Selectors.html) that helps to create the various kinds of built-in `Selector` implementations. There you can see references to the `PredicateSelector`. The `PredicateSelector` is very useful as it allows you complete control over the matching of the notification key. It can be a Spring `@Bean`, an anonymous inner class, a lambda, or anything else conforming to the simple `Predicate` interface.

Optionally, if you have the [JsonPath library](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/) in your classpath, then you can use the [`JsonPathSelector`](http://reactor.github.io/docs/api/reactor/io/selector/JsonPathSelector.html) to match based on JsonPath queries.

In either of these cases you don't need to have a separate object for a key if the important data is actually the domain object itself. Just notify on the object and pass the `Event<Object>` as the second parameter.

```
MyPojo p = service.next();
reactor.notify(p, Event.wrap(p));
```

Comment: Using `Predicate<T>` and the event as the key was exactly what was needed. I wonder how I did not think of using the actual event data as the key. Might be a good example to the Reactor wiki when adding more examples and use cases in the future. Anyway, Reactor looks definitely a good choice for us. Many thanks for your answer and looking forward to upcoming releases of a very promising library! :)